# Help with exposed filters please

Tags: views

[image]I have a content type called Profiles. Each profile has two filters, one is Location (East side or West Side) and the other is floor (2nd or 3rd). In the view I have set the profile to filter by location and floor. There is an employee who has an office on both the 2nd and 3rd floor in the east side and the 2nd floor on the west side but NOT on the 3rd floor in the West Side. But in the content filter I enabled all fields without thinking on one exception. How do I take care of this exception, please help

[image]

Comment: Do you have it setup with a multiselect picklist for the floors and locations they can be at? It doesn't sound like there is much of a problem, what are you choosing in the filter that is not working? The exposed filter works on an AND logic by default so: Show me
- Anyone at EAST AND on 2ND FLOOR
- Anyone at WEST AND on 2ND FLOOR The employee will show up when you select EAST AND 2ND, EAST AND 3RD, WEST AND 2ND, but won't if you chose WEST AND 3RD.

Comment: So if you see the attached images, you will see when I edit a profile those are the ways to set where the employee belongs. Then you look at the view you can see it is a dropdown but when I select the building as any or west side and floor as 3rd it shows true because I selected that for the particular employee.

Comment: Sounds like the filter is setup with OR instead of AND which is why it's showing the wrong result

Comment: Click Rearrange in the filter and change it to AND

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I appreciate it. Could you please let me know how to change that setting? I have been trying to find it all over for exposed filters.

Comment: In the filter, click there arrow next to Add and choose the arrange option. Then you will see the filter grouping. The operator should say OR, change that to AND